# SQLite com java, erro

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

Eu fiz um banco de dados de Contas Bancarias de um Banco, cada uma dessas contas tem seu `id` para identificar, e tem seu `tipo`, para saber qual o tipo da conta que o usuário ta acessando na quele momento, tipo, ele pode ter uma conta corrente e salario, são dois tipos de contas associadas a essa , então quero fazer a busca no meu banco usando o id da conta e o tipo que é inteiro também, mas ta dando erro.

```
Banco Conta = new Banco();

Conta.conectar();

ResultSet resultSet = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

String sql = "SELECT *FROM Contas WHERE NumeroConta = ? "
        + " AND Tipo = ?";

try{
    preparedStatement = Conta.criarPreparedStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, getNumConta());
    preparedStatement.setInt(5, getTipo());

    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    while(resultSet.next()){
        System.out.println(" " + resultSet.getFloat("Saldo"));
    }

}catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try{
        resultSet.close();
        preparedStatement.close();
        Conta.desconectar();
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Esse é o erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Usa.Busca.Trans(Busca.java:135)
    at Principal.main(Principal.java:82)
/home/nathan/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Comment: Esse é o método `Usa.Busca.Trans(Busca)`? Se sim, qual é a linha 135?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente alterar esta linha:

```
preparedStatement.setInt(5, getTipo());
```

Para:

```
preparedStatement.setInt(2, getTipo());
```

Já que na sua sentença tem somente 2 parametros e voce esta pulando do 1 para o 5.

Comment: muito obrigado, era isso mesmo